# How to add css in ngx datatable to only some columns?

Tags: css, sass, angular5, ngx-datatable

I have a following ngx datatable.

```
<ngx-datatable
      class="bootstrap"
      [rows]="dataRows"
      [columns]="dataColumns"
      (page)='setPage($event)'
      [loadingIndicator]="loadingData"
      [scrollbarH]="true">
</ngx-datatable>
```

It generates a simple table like below.

```
No. Name Num1 Num2 Num3
1    a    1   2    3
2    b    11  11   22
3    c    22  33   44
```

Now I need to add css only to 3 columns Num1, Num2 and Num3?

Can anybody help me ? I could not figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a css selector that skips the first two columns:

```
column-class:nth-child(n+3) {
* styling *
}
```